# Displaying an image with EJS in node.js/express

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm just trying to get setup with node.js/express/ejs. I know ejs isn't actual HTML and so I'm having a hard time just displaying a simple image. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Directory structure is:

- myApp/server.js
- myApp/views/index.ejs
- myApp/logo.jpg

Right now I have

```
// index.ejs
<img src = "../logo.jpg" />
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Very accurate explanation.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Static files in Express must go inside the directory specified in your `static` middleware. This is commonly `./public/`.

For example, in your `server.js` you may have something like this:

```
app.use( express.static( "public" ) );
```

Each file inside this folder will be accessible from the root URL, so this will work:

```
<img src="logo.jpg" />
```

Comment: Oh ok that worked! I'm not exactly sure how though. Is there only 1 directory that is able to be 'static'? And sources are automatically directed there?

Comment: You may add various static middlewares after that one, they will work the same way. If the file is not found in that directory, it goes to the next middleware...

Answer (score 14):

You have to assign `app.use( express.static( "public" ) );` on app.js then don't forget the / as root:

```
<img src="/images/logo.jpg" />
```

the images folder should be in public folder:

```
- public/
  - images/
    - logo.png
- app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

My `js` file was here `c:/blog/index.js` and image file `c:/blog/views/image.js`. And entered `js` file this code

`app.use( express.static( "views" ) );`

then in CSS  added property

`body {

background-image: url("./image.jpg");
 }`