# How to display images stored in Mongodb using Node.Js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I need your help on displaying images stored in MongoDB using Node.JS and express framework.

I've successfully saved the image using this method:

```
var multer  = require('multer'); 

//var upload = multer({ dest: 'public/Images/' }); 

var fs = require("fs");



    var storage = multer.diskStorage({

  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'public/Images/')
  },

  filename: function (req, file, cb) {

     //cb(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now())
    cb(null,  Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname); 
  }

});


var upload = multer({storage: storage}); 


var user = require('../app/model/user');


        app.post('/upload', upload.single('meme'), function (req, res, next) {



        if (req.file){

    var host = req.hostname;

    var filePath = req.protocol + "://" + host + '/' + 'public/Images/' + req.file.originalname;

    //console.log(filePath); 

    var newMeme = new user(); 

    newMeme.meme.imgs = filePath; 

    newMeme.uploadDate = Date.now(); 

    newMeme.save(function (err) {

        if (err)

            throw err; 

        //console('Meme saved'); 
    }); 

        return res.send({

            success: true
        })  ;




            } else {


                console.log('failed'); 

                res.send({

                    success: false 


                }); 



            }

    })
```

I'm now lost when it comes to displaying the images stored.

These are the stuff I want to display:

[image: Images stored]

please, can someone help? I'm using express JS and ejs as my view engine.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755147/displaying-an-image-with-ejs-in-node-js-express refer this

Comment: can you share your server.js code?

Comment: There's nothing there that can help you solve the question.

Comment: @Kannan I want to display them from the database.