# How to Upload img in Ejs From Upload Folder in Nodejs

Tags: ejs, multer

I m successfully able to load img into MongoDB and My server Folder as well ..
Im facing an issue to access them in Img tag in ejs template,
Although Img is successfully uploaded both DB and upload but facing to get in EJS,
All examples over the Internet I've tried but fail...

Router Part:

```
var uploadMultiple = upload.fields([{ name: 'profileimage', maxCount: 1 },{ name: 'galleryimg1', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'galleryimg2', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'galleryimg3' , maxCount: 1}, { name: 'galleryimg4', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'galleryimg5', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'galleryimg6', maxCount: 1 }])

router.post('/explorePakistanProfile',uploadMultiple, (req, res ,next) => {
    // get all the values 
    const ExplorePakistandata = new  ExplorePakistan({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        contact: req.body.contact,
        destination: req.body.destination,
        posteddate: req.body.posteddate,
        nearestlocation: req.body.nearestlocation,
        tripdescription: req.body.tripdescription,
        profileimage: req.files.profileimage[0].path,
        galleryimg1: req.files.galleryimg1[0].path,
        galleryimg2:req.files.galleryimg2[0].path,
        galleryimg3: req.files.galleryimg3[0].path,
        galleryimg4: req.files.galleryimg4[0].path,
        galleryimg5: req.files.galleryimg5[0].path,
        galleryimg6: req.files.galleryimg6[0].path,
        province:req.body.province,
        fb:req.body.fb,
        instagram:req.body.instagram,
        youtube:req.body.youtube,
        blogs:req.body.blogs,
        aeratag1:req.body.aeratag1,
        aeratag2:req.body.aeratag2,
    })

   console.log(ExplorePakistandata.profileimage)
 
    console.log(ExplorePakistandata)
    // check if the are empty 
    if (!ExplorePakistandata.name   || !ExplorePakistandata.email|| !ExplorePakistandata.contact|| !ExplorePakistandata.destination|| !ExplorePakistandata.posteddate|| !ExplorePakistandata.nearestlocation|| !ExplorePakistandata.tripdescription|| !ExplorePakistandata.profileimage||!ExplorePakistandata.aeratag1 || !ExplorePakistandata.aeratag2 ||  !ExplorePakistandata.galleryimg1 || !ExplorePakistandata.galleryimg2 || !ExplorePakistandata.galleryimg3 || !ExplorePakistandata.galleryimg4 || !ExplorePakistandata.galleryimg5 || !ExplorePakistandata.galleryimg6)  {
        console.log("All Fields Required")
        res.render("explorepakistan/explorePakistanProfile", { err: "All Fields Required !" });
    } 
     else {
        ExplorePakistan.findOne({ $or: [{ email: ExplorePakistandata.email }, { contact: ExplorePakistandata.contact }] }, function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;

            if (data) {
                res.render("explorepakistan/explorePakistanProfile", { err: "User  Already exist" });
                console.log(`"User  Already exist" ${data}`)
            } else {

                                ExplorePakistandata.save((err, data) => {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                console.log(data)
                                res.redirect('/explorepakistan')
                            });
                    }
        });
    };
});
```

EJS Part:

```
<%if (records.length>0){ %>
    <% records.forEach(function(expolrepakistan){ %>
        <!-- Explore Pakistan Data  -->

        <main class="container">
            <div class="h1 text-center" id="pageHeaderTitle">My Cards</div>

            <article class="postcard blue">
                <a class="postcard__img_link" href="#">
                      <img class="postcard__img" src=".//uploads/<%=expolrepakistan.galleryimg1 %>" alt="BloggerProfile" />
                

                </a>
                <div class="postcard__text">
                    <img src="./uploads/<%=expolrepakistan.profileimage %>" alt="authorimg" class="authorimg">
                  <h1 class="postcard__title blue">
                    <a href="#" class="mapoverflow">
                    <label for="expdatalabel">Destination:
                    <span class="locationmain"><%= expolrepakistan.destination %></span>
                  </label> 
                  </a>
                  </h1>
```

Note: All setup of Multer is Done And working Properly that is why I m not posting that part here...

Please Please Please Help me to do , I've to submit that today As I'm a newbie and student

Comment: Do you have a static middleware in your server configuratin ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755147/displaying-an-image-with-ejs-in-node-js-express

Comment: yes every thing is okie 
even i m access all other data in Ejs accept images

Comment: I already go through link that you mention,

Comment: so, maybe instead of using url  like -  "./uploads/..." try to - "/uploads/..."

Comment: let me check it....please dont go anywhere

Comment: <img class="postcard__img" src="/uploads/<%=expolrepakistan.galleryimg1 %>" alt="BloggerProfile" />
i try this but not working

Comment: can you share errors from console or response errors ?

Comment: there is no error, all images are uploaded in uploads folder as we'll save in DB..

Just I'm not able to access in img tag

Comment: <img class="postcard__img" src="/uploads/<%=expolrepakistan.galleryimg1 %>" alt="BloggerProfile" />

just geeting prob that how to access a file in img tags