# How add a <img/> in .ejs file

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have problems to add a img in my `.ejs` file. I'm using `.ejs` to be a email template and a I need to add a image but I can't. I am new in Node.js and Stack Overflow, I put some information about my code below.

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')))`

```
api
 |public\assets
  |my imgs
 |utils\emails
  |templates
   |fundo-img.png
```

`<img alt="Match" src="<%= apiHost %><%= assetsPath %>fundo-img.png">`

At the inspetor are showing this `src`.

```
<img alt="Match" src="https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/v-dLlD45vWXlJpH04tlKxlrCizE8zE358c6baY1fx-ifMVMVGS_5NbkyEBnkiktqAwIotKglLd1csGXcbQ=s0-d-e1-ft#http://localhost:3001/assets/fundo-img.png">
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6uQB.png)

If you need information to help me, I will see what I can show, because this project is not 100% mine.

Comment: your image `fundo-img.png` should be inside the `public` directory (or inside a subdirectory of `public`) in order for express to serve it as a static resource.

Comment: You can follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755147/displaying-an-image-with-ejs-in-node-js-express)  accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the gmail. I tried in another email and `<img alt="Match" src="<%= apiHost %><%= assetsPath %>fundo-img.png">` works.

Comment: Please concider marking your answer as the solution (once that is possible).

Comment: Thanks @Dennis.

Answer (score 0):

If you're currently running your api locally, you should just remove the <%= apiHost %> part.
A path should just be a relative path from your server js file to the image directory. That way it will work both locally and when hosted somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Marijana!