# Images not showing up, despite having the correct path

Tags: html, css

This might be a really stupid question, but here goes nothing

Currently I have the following in my HTML:

```
<div class="disk-images">
        <img src="../public/images/blueflame.png">
        <img src="../public/images/purpleflamelogo.jpg">
</div>
```

I have not styled it in my CSS, but AFAIK, this should not be a problem, as the default style sheet should still take care of it.

I also know the path to these images is correct as, when I Ctrl + click on it in VSCode, it shows me the image.

This is what it shows instead:
[image]

This would suggest, that the path to the images are wrong, however, as previously stated, I do believe the path is correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the absolute path of the HTML file on disk, and what are the absolute paths of the two images?  Also, do you have some build or deploy step that packages everything up and, e.g., copies it to your web server?  I guess what I'm getting at is, when you open the site in the browser, are you viewing the HTML file that you edited in VS code or a copy of it that's been deployed somewhere else?

Comment: Is your browser also vscode? Open up the network tab in your dev tools and check from which path the images are being loaded. You have the wrong path in your html, i guarantee you.

Comment: @adv12

Absoloute Path of HTML:
"C:\VSCode\JavaScript\connectfour\views\splash.ejs"

Absoloute Path of IMG 1 (kept in same directory as IMG 2):
"C:\VSCode\JavaScript\connectfour\public\images\purpleflamelogo.jpg"

Using express to deploy it locally.  Usually the changes are reflected each time I type ```npm start``` and that hasn't given me any issues before.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I'm unfamiliar with ejs and how it's deployed, but you may find that, upon deployment, the location of the page actually loaded in the browser differs from the location of your ejs file (relative to the deployed image path)

Comment: Turns out it was an express shenanigan specified here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17755226/16786391

Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people having the same problem in the future, the problem was with express and how static files in express work.

I had the following in my `app.js`

```
app.use( express.static( "public" ) );
```

which meant the root folder for my static assets was actually another directory.

You can read up on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17755226/16786391)

Answer (score 1):

**relatively path is correct** but the files in the public folder are static files such as index.html, javascript library files, images, and other assets, etc. Files in this folder are copied and pasted as they are directly into the build folder. Only files inside the public folder can be referenced from the HTML.

Updated code:

```
<div class="disk-images">
   <img src="images/blueflame.png">
   <img src="images/purpleflamelogo.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check your console for any 404 messages, and try to close the whole project and re-open it in your editor and browser as you may working on an old version