# Hyperlink image in css in express-ejs

Tags: express, ejs

I have the following code:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path');
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const ejs = require('ejs');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('homepage');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

My public folder is:

```
public:
  css: [bunch of css files]
  images:[bunch of images]
```

When I try to link image in css that resides in public folder, it does not work:

```
.mainContainer {
    flex-direction: column;
    background-image: url('images/myImage.jpg');
    background-position: 50% 0%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

But if I put the `background-image` property in `ejs` template then it works fine because it finds the image in public directory. I dont want to put `background-image` property in `ejs`. How do I make it work from css file?

I found similar questions but they are doing it through ejs: [Displaying an image with EJS in node.js/express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755147/displaying-an-image-with-ejs-in-node-js-express)